# Copy Concatenation in AppleScript as a command

Tags: macos, copy, applescript, concatenation, shortcut

so I have a quick question for anyone willing to help. When I am programming in a regular text editor, I often find myself wanting to copy multiple lines of code, concatenating them on the fly and then being able to paste their contents just like I would normally use Command+c/Command+v.

I think this would be done in Applescript and then assigned a custom shortcut with Quicksilver but I am not too familiar with either. Below is an example to illustrate the desired behavior.

```
Copy-Concatenate with Command+C+X  Paste with Command+V  Clear Clipboard when regular Command+C is used

so...
Command+C+X "First line" ... Command+C+x"Second line" ... Command+V pastes "First lineSecond line"
and Command+C"Third line"... Command+V pastes "Third line"
```

Can someone help me accomplish this or set me on the right path? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text in your editor and try this:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "x" using command down
set myText to the clipboard as «class utf8»
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {return, linefeed, character id 8233, character id 8232}}
set myText to text items of myText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
set the clipboard to myText as text
set text item delimiters to TID
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```